# Physical printing with Electron PDF

Tags: pdf

I have a project where I use Electron PDF to generate PDF files from HTML which are then sent to an external bureau who print them and send to customers.

Now, they've sent me some headers that they want in the PDF file, and I wonder how to encode these PDF headers into my final file. I rarely work with PDFs.

The file they sent me (called `joboptions`) contains the following information:

```
    <<
  /ASCII85EncodePages false
  /AllowPSXObjects false
  /AllowTransparency true
  /AlwaysEmbed [
    true
  ]
  /AntiAliasColorImages false
  /AntiAliasGrayImages false
  /AntiAliasMonoImages false
  /AutoFilterColorImages true
  /AutoFilterGrayImages true
  /AutoPositionEPSFiles true
  /AutoRotatePages /None
  /Binding /Left
  /CalCMYKProfile (None)
  /CalGrayProfile (Dot Gain 20%)
  /CalRGBProfile (Adobe RGB \0501998\051)
  /CannotEmbedFontPolicy /Warning
  /CheckCompliance [
    /None
  ]
  /ColorACSImageDict <<
    /HSamples [
      1
      1
      1
      1
    ]
    /QFactor 0.15000
    /VSamples [
      1
      1
      1
      1
    ]
  >>
  /ColorConversionStrategy /UseDeviceIndependentColor
  /ColorImageAutoFilterStrategy /JPEG
  /ColorImageDepth -1
  /ColorImageDict <<
    /HSamples [
      1
      1
      1
      1
    ]
    /QFactor 0.15000
    /VSamples [
      1
      1
      1
      1
    ]
  >>
  /ColorImageDownsampleThreshold 1.50000
  /ColorImageDownsampleType /Bicubic
  /ColorImageFilter /DCTEncode
  /ColorImageMinDownsampleDepth 1
  /ColorImageMinResolution 300
  /ColorImageMinResolutionPolicy /OK
  /ColorImageResolution 300
  /ColorSettingsFile ()
  /CompatibilityLevel 1.4
  /CompressObjects /Tags
  /CompressPages true
  /ConvertImagesToIndexed true
  /CreateJDFFile false
  /CreateJobTicket false
  /CropColorImages false
  /CropGrayImages false
  /CropMonoImages false
  /DSCReportingLevel 0
  /DefaultRenderingIntent /Default
  /Description <<
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
  >>
  /DetectBlends true
  /DetectCurves 0
  /DoThumbnails false
  /DownsampleColorImages true
  /DownsampleGrayImages true
  /DownsampleMonoImages true
  /EmbedAllFonts true
  /EmbedJobOptions true
  /EmbedOpenType false
  /EmitDSCWarnings false
  /EncodeColorImages true
  /EncodeGrayImages true
  /EncodeMonoImages true
  /EndPage -1
  /GrayACSImageDict <<
    /HSamples [
      1
      1
      1
      1
    ]
    /QFactor 0.15000
    /VSamples [
      1
      1
      1
      1
    ]
  >>
  /GrayImageAutoFilterStrategy /JPEG
  /GrayImageDepth -1
  /GrayImageDict <<
    /HSamples [
      1
      1
      1
      1
    ]
    /QFactor 0.15000
    /VSamples [
      1
      1
      1
      1
    ]
  >>
  /GrayImageDownsampleThreshold 1.50000
  /GrayImageDownsampleType /Bicubic
  /GrayImageFilter /DCTEncode
  /GrayImageMinDownsampleDepth 2
  /GrayImageMinResolution 300
  /GrayImageMinResolutionPolicy /OK
  /GrayImageResolution 300
  /ImageMemory 1048576
  /JPEG2000ColorACSImageDict <<
    /Quality 30
    /TileHeight 256
    /TileWidth 256
  >>
  /JPEG2000ColorImageDict <<
    /Quality 30
    /TileHeight 256
    /TileWidth 256
  >>
  /JPEG2000GrayACSImageDict <<
    /Quality 30
    /TileHeight 256
    /TileWidth 256
  >>
  /JPEG2000GrayImageDict <<
    /Quality 30
    /TileHeight 256
    /TileWidth 256
  >>
  /LockDistillerParams false
  /MaxSubsetPct 100
  /MonoImageDepth -1
  /MonoImageDict <<
    /K -1
  >>
  /MonoImageDownsampleThreshold 1.50000
  /MonoImageDownsampleType /Bicubic
  /MonoImageFilter /CCITTFaxEncode
  /MonoImageMinResolution 1200
  /MonoImageMinResolutionPolicy /OK
  /MonoImageResolution 1200
  /Namespace [
    (Adobe)
    (Common)
    (1.0)
  ]
  /NeverEmbed [
    true
  ]
  /OPM 1
  /Optimize false
  /OtherNamespaces [
    <<
      /AsReaderSpreads false
      /CropImagesToFrames true
      /ErrorControl /WarnAndContinue
      /FlattenerIgnoreSpreadOverrides false
      /IncludeGuidesGrids false
      /IncludeNonPrinting false
      /IncludeSlug false
      /Namespace [
        (Adobe)
        (InDesign)
        (4.0)
      ]
      /OmitPlacedBitmaps false
      /OmitPlacedEPS false
      /OmitPlacedPDF false
      /SimulateOverprint /Legacy
    >>
    <<
      /AddBleedMarks false
      /AddColorBars false
      /AddCropMarks true
      /AddPageInfo false
      /AddRegMarks false
      /BleedOffset [
        8.50394
        8.50394
        8.50394
        8.50394
      ]
      /ConvertColors /NoConversion
      /DestinationProfileName ()
      /DestinationProfileSelector /NA
      /Downsample16BitImages true
      /FlattenerPreset <<
        /PresetSelector /HighResolution
      >>
      /FormElements false
      /GenerateStructure false
      /IncludeBookmarks false
      /IncludeHyperlinks false
      /IncludeInteractive false
      /IncludeLayers false
      /IncludeProfiles true
      /MarksOffset 6
      /MarksWeight 0.25000
      /MultimediaHandling /UseObjectSettings
      /Namespace [
        (Adobe)
        (CreativeSuite)
        (2.0)
      ]
      /PDFXOutputIntentProfileSelector /DocumentCMYK
      /PageMarksFile /RomanDefault
      /PreserveEditing true
      /UntaggedCMYKHandling /LeaveUntagged
      /UntaggedRGBHandling /UseDocumentProfile
      /UseDocumentBleed false
    >>
    <<
      /AllowImageBreaks true
      /AllowTableBreaks true
      /ExpandPage false
      /HonorBaseURL true
      /HonorRolloverEffect false
      /IgnoreHTMLPageBreaks false
      /IncludeHeaderFooter false
      /MarginOffset [
        0
        0
        0
        0
      ]
      /MetadataAuthor ()
      /MetadataKeywords ()
      /MetadataSubject ()
      /MetadataTitle ()
      /MetricPageSize [
        0
        0
      ]
      /MetricUnit /inch
      /MobileCompatible 0
      /Namespace [
        (Adobe)
        (GoLive)
        (8.0)
      ]
      /OpenZoomToHTMLFontSize false
      /PageOrientation /Portrait
      /RemoveBackground false
      /ShrinkContent true
      /TreatColorsAs /MainMonitorColors
      /UseEmbeddedProfiles false
      /UseHTMLTitleAsMetadata true
    >>
  ]
  /PDFX1aCheck false
  /PDFX3Check false
  /PDFXBleedBoxToTrimBoxOffset [
    0
    0
    0
    0
  ]
  /PDFXCompliantPDFOnly true
  /PDFXNoTrimBoxError false
  /PDFXOutputCondition ()
  /PDFXOutputConditionIdentifier (FOGRA27)
  /PDFXOutputIntentProfile (Coated FOGRA27 \050ISO 12647-2:2004\051)
  /PDFXRegistryName (http://www.color.org)
  /PDFXSetBleedBoxToMediaBox true
  /PDFXTrapped /False
  /PDFXTrimBoxToMediaBoxOffset [
    0
    0
    0
    0
  ]
  /ParseDSCComments true
  /ParseDSCCommentsForDocInfo true
  /ParseICCProfilesInComments true
  /PassThroughJPEGImages true
  /PreserveCopyPage true
  /PreserveDICMYKValues true
  /PreserveEPSInfo true
  /PreserveFlatness false
  /PreserveHalftoneInfo false
  /PreserveOPIComments false
  /PreserveOverprintSettings true
  /StartPage 1
  /SubsetFonts true
  /TransferFunctionInfo /Apply
  /UCRandBGInfo /Remove
  /UsePrologue false
  /sRGBProfile (sRGB IEC61966-2.1)
>> setdistillerparams
<<
  /HWResolution [2400 2400]
  /PageSize [612.000 792.000]
>> setpagedevice
```

How do I get this information encoded into my final PDF file?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

a joboptions file contains instructions for building the PDF file. It's usually used in Adobe apps and come once loaded as options when one choose to export a file to PDF. I don't know a thing about electron PDF but unless you can use a joboptions file to generate the PDF (which I doubt of), you are hitting a wall.

Comment: Thanks Loic. This helps me understand at least how to use the file. I'll see if I can find an implementation when programmatically generating the PDF-file.

Answer (score 0):

`joboptions` config file is the file to stored settings for pdf generation by Adobe Distiller application. So you should either have Adobe Destiller installed on a final computer or you should just try to set option in the pdf package you use to match these options.